# I am getting a IndexError: list index out of range in pygame/python

Tags: python

So I am making a game in `pygame` and for the graphics I watched a
[Clear Code tutorial](https://youtu.be/QU1pPzEGrqw)

```
for style,layout in layout.items():
    for row_index,row in enumerate(layout):
        for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
            if col != '-1':
                x = col_index * TILE_SIZE
                y = row_index * TILE_SIZE
                if style == 'boundary':
                    Tile((x,y),[self.obstacle_spites],'invisible')
                if style == 'nature':
                    surf = graphics['nature'][int(col)]
                    Tile((x,y),[self.visible_sprites],'nature',surf)
```

In `surf = graphics['nature'][int(col)]`
I am getting an `IndexError: list index out of range error`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score -2):

it's happen because you access a list by index where the index is out of range of the len(your_list) - 1.

example :
your_list = ['a', 'b']
len(your_list) is 2. so max index that you can access to list is 2 - 1, which is 1.

they are : your_list[0] or your_list[1].

if you try your_list[2], it will raise an error list index out of range as you are facing now.

in your case:
maybe you can handle error like this:

```
- if you want to avoid the error and let it empty:
try:
   surf = graphics['nature'][int(col)]
   Tile((x,y),[self.visible_sprites],'nature',surf)
except Exception as err:
   print ('please check your nature value')
```